# Combine results from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is a simplified schema of my data :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id`         VARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
  `name`       VARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
  `url`        VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  `data_date`  DATE                NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY(`id`, `data_date`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_views_by_id` (
  `id`         VARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
  `views`      INT(16)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `data_date`  DATE           NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY(`id`, `data_date`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_views_by_url` (
  `url`        VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
  `views`      INT(16)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `data_date`  DATE           NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY(`url`, `data_date`)
);
```

Example data :

```
INSERT INTO `posts`
  (`id`, `name`, `url`, `data_date`)
VALUES
  ("1a", "name1", "url1", "2016-08-08"),
  ("1b", "name2", "url2", "2016-08-08"),
  ("1c", "name3", "url3", "2016-08-08"),
  ("1a", "name1", "url1", "2016-08-09"),
  ("1b", "name2", "url2", "2016-08-09"),
  ("1c", "name3", "url3", "2016-08-09");


INSERT INTO `post_views_by_id`
  (`id`, `views`, `data_date`)
VALUES
  ("1a", 10, "2016-08-08"),
  ("1b", 15, "2016-08-08"),
  ("1a", 12, "2016-08-09"),
  ("1b", 17, "2016-08-09");


INSERT INTO `post_views_by_url`
  (`url`, `views`, `data_date`)
VALUES
  ("url3", 22, "2016-08-08"),
  ("url3", 12, "2016-08-09");
```

I am trying to create a query which will return a list of posts with view numbers from the 3 tables combined.

When i do only one join ...

```
SELECT 
  p.id        AS 'post_id',
  p.name      AS 'post_name',
  p.url       AS 'post_url',
  pbi.views   AS 'post_views',
  p.data_date AS 'date'
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN post_views_by_id pbi
  ON p.id = pbi.id
WHERE p.data_date   = "2016-08-08"
  AND pbi.data_date = "2016-08-08"
```

i get a result :

```
id  name    url     views   data_date
1a  name1   url1    10  August, 08 2016 00:00:00
1b  name2   url2    15  August, 08 2016 00:00:00
```

Now i want to combine the third table, where views are stored with url.

```
SELECT 
   p.id        AS 'post_id',
   p.name      AS 'post_name',
   p.url       AS 'post_url',
   pbi.views   AS 'post_views_id',
   pbu.views   AS 'post_views_url',
   p.data_date AS 'date'
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN post_views_by_id pbi
   ON p.id = pbi.id
INNER JOIN post_views_by_url pbu
   ON p.url = pbu.url
WHERE p.data_date   = "2016-08-08"
  AND pbi.data_date = "2016-08-08"
  AND pbu.data_date = "2016-08-08"
```

Then i got no results at all ..

I'm not really sure how to construct the right query. i have read many posts here on SO about multiple joins , but none of them really helped me to solve the problem.

The expected result should be :

```
id  name    url     views   data_date
1a  name1   url1    10      August, 08 2016 00:00:00
1b  name2   url2    15      August, 08 2016 00:00:00
1c  name3   url3    22      August, 08 2016 00:00:00
```

**[SQL Fiddle for the question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d3e93/27)**

Comment: Why not have a table which store post id, url, and id?

Comment: In addition to @prdp answer, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d3e93/45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not wrong you need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT p.id        AS 'post_id', 
       p.NAME      AS 'post_name', 
       p.url       AS 'post_url', 
       pbi.views   AS 'post_views_id', 
       pbu.views   AS 'post_views_url', 
       p.data_date AS 'date' 
FROM   posts p 
       LEFT JOIN post_views_by_id pbi 
              ON p.id = pbi.id 
                 AND pbi.data_date = p.data_date 
       LEFT JOIN post_views_by_url pbu 
              ON p.url = pbu.url 
                 AND pbu.data_date = p.data_date 
WHERE  p.data_date = '2016-08-08'
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf00f/16)